# Proving the greatest common divisor (number theory)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that for all $a, b, c \in \mathbb N$
>
> $\gcd(a,bc)=1~~~$ if and only if $~~~\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1$

$$~$$
*What I tried*
**1)**$~~~\gcd(a,bc)=1 \implies \gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1$

$$\gcd(a,bc)=1 \implies \exists x, \exists y, ax+bcy=1$$

Because $\gcd(a,b)=1\text{ means }ak_{1}+bk_{2}=1$

Hence we get the two equations 
$$ax+bcy=1$$
$$ak_{1}+bk_{2}=1$$

Combining both eqauations we get,

$$ax+(1-ak_{1})cy=1$$

Hence we have $~~~\gcd(a,c)=1$

$$~$$
**2)** $~~~\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1\implies \gcd(a,bc)=1$

We have

$$gcd(a,b) \text{ means }ak_{1}+bk_{2}=1$$
$$\gcd(a,c) \text{ means }ak_{3}+ck_{4}=1$$

I'm stuck here however as I'm unsure of how to form the equation that forms $\gcd(a,bc)=1$ and is my workings correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first direction, when proving that $\gcd(a,bc)=1\implies \gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1$, I don't think you can use $\gcd(a,b)=1$ to construct the second equation (because then you'd be assuming what you want to prove.)

However, note that $\gcd(a,bc)=1 \implies ax+bcy=1$ for some $x,y \in \Bbb Z$, as you wrote, and this equation is enough to conclude:

$$ax+b(cy)=1 \implies \gcd(a,b)=1\\
ax+c(by)=1\implies \gcd(a,c)=1.$$

For the second direction, you can just multiply your equations $ak_1+bk_2=1$ and $ak_3+ck_4=1$:

$$1=(ak_1+bk_2)(ak_3+ck_4)=a(ak_1k_2+ck_1k_4+bk_2k_3)+bc(k_2k_4),$$

which implies that $\gcd(a,bc)=1$.

Comment: Okay i see. then how about the second direction?

Answer (score 1):

$$(bk_2)(ck_4)=1-a(k_1+k_3-ak_1k_3)\iff bc(k_2k_4)+a(k_1+k_3-ak_1k_3)=1$$

Comment: Okay so this part is just simply algebraic manipulation? Is my approach to solving the question correct? Thanks

Comment: @yswong, Yes, see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma